# What software can I use to make a mirror image of Ubuntu?

Tags: backup

I used to use Easeus Todo for Windows, or Norton Ghost. What options do I have for linux?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just cloned my hdd, easily and quickly with no errors, i used clonzilla, a brilliant bit of software.

It allows you to clone HDD to HDD, or HDD to image, plus other options.

I can't stress how easy it is to use...

Some info here:

[Top 6 Open Source Disk Cloning and Imaging Software](http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/linux-based-disk-cloning-imaging-software/)

Answer (score 0):

Clonezilla is great for cloning Windows and Linux. You can boot it from USB/CD/PXE and image to files on an external drive, samba, nfs,  & ssh. You can also disk to disk.

Answer (score 0):

To make a backup of linux, you can use the tar or dd command.

In order to answer this question it may be useful to know if you want a regular backup that runs automatically (e.g. create a copy of the system and store it in the *cloud* (e.g. **Amazon Glacier**), or just do a quick once off backup to a local hard drive.

The beauty of linux is that there are many ways to do it, from manual to fully automated.

Tar See: [Techrepublic](http://b2b.cbsimg.net/downloads/PDF/SolutionBase_Backup_Linux_reliably_with_rsync_and_tar.pdf for some additional details.)

dd: See [dd](http://dimitar.me/clone-disk-drives-with-ubuntu/)

Oh, and do take care and read the instructions thoroughly and run a test on a spare machine first, as these commands are powerful, but once you have mastered it you can save the command as your own software to run when you need to.